# ionic cordova local notifications sounds not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to build my ionic mobile app with local notifications and I want to include sound in the notification. I already tried adding a sound file to the resources folder and add the below code. But still not working.

```
     recurringMonthAlarm(alarmdata,eleindex){
      this.localNotifications.schedule({
       id: eleindex,
       title: alarmdata.title,
       text: alarmdata.desc,
       sound: this.setSound(),
       foreground: true,
       trigger: {firstAt: alarmdata.startTime,
         every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.MONTH
       }
      
    });
  }

  

    setSound() {
        return 'file://audio/alarmsound.wav';
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your File Path Issue, Add your sound file in your assets folder.

Try:

```
setSound() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      return 'file://assets/sounds/shame.mp3' // for Android
    } else {
      return 'file://assets/sounds/bell.mp3' // for iOS
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, @Najam Us Saqib Thanks for yout comment. But where should I put the sound file? What is the location path?

Comment: in your assets folder. same as your images. create `sounds`  folder in your asset folder.

Comment: try an online path. something like: `http://yourdomain.com/sound/shame.mp3`  host your sound file somewhere and use it.

Comment: I need to run my app without insternet connection

Comment: try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827283/5909026

Comment: tried, but still no luck. I think there's some issue with android 10 version.

Comment: have you tried it with older android version??

Comment: it could be a dirty workaround but try `cordova native Audio` plugin to play your sound: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio